# Create a folder with batch file in c:\Program Files(x86)\

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to make an installer and i need to create a folder in Program Files (x86).
I created a batch file with the following code:

```
@echo off

copy  /s "c:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\MagicPanelInst\magicpanel" "c:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Adobe\CEP\extensions\"
```

I pretend to copy from magicpanel from the source to the already existing folder extensions in the target...

But is created in c: a new folder called Program Files (x86) with all the directories described above, instead of copy the magicpanel folder to the existing one.

Any help please?

Comment: I don't understand the question. You say that there is an existing folder `c:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Adobe\CEP\extensions\ ` which implies that `c:\Program Files (x86)` exists but then you contradict yourself by saying that it creates a _new_ folder also called the same thing - `c:\Program Files (x86)`. That's very confusing. What exactly do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Now it is working with the below code.

```
xcopy /s "c:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\MagicPanelInst\magicpanel" "%programfiles(x86)%\Common Files\Adobe\CEP\extensions\magicpanel" /i
```

Or even better:

```
xcopy /s "%UserProfile%\Desktop\MagicPanelInst\magicpanel" "%CommonProgramFiles(x86)%\Adobe\CEP\extensions\magicpanel" /i
```

Thank you all for the help.